# How to resolve Auto layout constraints in Cosmic Materials

Tags: swift, autolayout, material-design, cosmicmind

I am using  **CosmicMind/Material** [For Material Layout in iOS](http://github.com/CosmicMind/Material)
and I wanna add multiplier, priority and Identifier in its Layout constraints.
e.g.

`let parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500)) 
let childView = UIView()
parentView.layout.topLeft(childView, top: 50, left: 50)`

How to add multiplier, priority and Identifier in child view and also parent view

References from http://www.cosmicmind.io

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you cannot. That said, I will add the ability to do so in an upcoming update. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your anticipation,
I'm waiting for new update

Answer (score 0):

which error do you have?
remember to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to **false** for each `UIView`